# python 3.2, tkinter. Use functions and graphics to return a variable when a button is pressed

Tags: function, button, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make it so my main() function calls upon the getWordUser() function to make a button. Once the button is pressed, the Word_and_Username() function is called to return the username and the word. For some reason, I can't get it to work. Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import*
import random
root = Tk()
root.title("Hangman")
root.geometry("200x200")
username = ""

def Word_and_Username():
    file = open("Hangmanwords.txt","r")
    randomize = random.randint(1,117)
    words = file.readlines()
    line = words[randomize]
    word = line[:-1]
    username = root.username.get()

    return word,username

def getWordUser():
    root.username = Entry()
    root.username.grid(row=1, column=0)

    root.theGame = Button(text = "Continue", command=Word_and_Username)
    root.theGame.grid(row=1, column=1)

def main():
    getWordUser()
    print (username)



main()
root.mainloop()
```

basically, I need main to call the function, wait until the continue button is pressed and return the variables to main while continuing on with the main function. Thanks.

Comment: Having callback functions "return" makes no sense in the context of a GUI. Where do you think they will get returned to?

Are you creating a GUI, or something like a command line program that only briefly shows a window to get a single input value?

Comment: I want to create a GUI that has a main function which calls on the username function to allow the user to input a username and then stores that username function for later use.

Comment: so it follows this rubric: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Vf0OccwvdS9Pd9rjp_3S86_yyTE8WHqqAIkUfS3K_vk/edit#

Answer (score 0):

You can have the values stored and ready to use in a very straighforward way by assigning them to a root property.
This is your modified script showing that. Press 'What I know' to see in the shell the word for a given user.

```
from Tkinter import*
import random
root = Tk()
root.title("Hangman")
root.geometry("250x200")
root.word = None
root.user = None

def Word_and_Username():
    file = open("C:/test/test.csv","r")
    randomize = random.randint(1,4)
    words = file.readlines()
    line = words[randomize]
    root.word = line[:-1]
    root.user = root.username.get()

def getWordUser():
    root.username = Entry()
    root.username.grid(row=1, column=0)

    root.theGame = Button(text = "Continue", command=Word_and_Username)
    root.theGame.grid(row=1, column=1)

    root.ask = Button(text = "What I know", command=ask)
    root.ask.grid(row=2, column=1)

def ask():
    print 'word is %s for user %s' %(root.word, root.user)


getWordUser()
root.mainloop()
```